# Initializing the serial ports for transferring data

Tags: uart, serial

I'm trying to use the serial port (COM) to send/receive data over the serial device and also want to use the serial port in polling mode.

I use the following code to initialize the serial port.

```
VOID CpInitialize( PCPPORT Port, PUCHAR  Address, ULONG  Rate)
{
PUCHAR hwport;
UCHAR   mcr, ier;

Port->Address = Address;
Port->Baud = 0;

CpSetBaud(Port, Rate);

// Assert DTR, RTS.
hwport = Port->Address;
hwport += COM_MCR;

mcr = MC_DTRRTS;
_outp(hwport, mcr);

hwport = Port->Address;
hwport += COM_IEN;

ier = 0;
_outp(hwport, ier);
}
```

and pass **115200** as **Rate** and **COM2_PORT** as the **Address**.

```
#define COM1_PORT   0x03f8
#define COM2_PORT   0x02f8
#define COM3_PORT   0x03e8
#define COM4_PORT   0x02e8
```

And finally, for sending a byte out, I use the following function.

```
VOID CpPutByte(PCPPORT  Port,   UCHAR   Byte)
{
if (KdDbgPortsPresent == FALSE) {
    return;
}
//  Wait for port to not be busy
while (!(CpReadLsr(Port, COM_OUTRDY) & COM_OUTRDY));

// Send the byte
_outp(Port->Address + COM_DAT, Byte);
}
```

In order to test the above functions, I create a Serial Device in VMWare Workstation and connect to the Windbg debugger using kdnet. (I don't use COM for debugging of Windbg.).

The problem is nothing transfers to the other side but if use I a usermode applications then I can successfully transfer data over the serial but it's not possible to send bytes over serial using the above code.

I further investigated the problem and find a sample from Microsoft in SDK which is called "**kdserial**".

After using the "**kdserial**" codes, I have the exact same problem and tracing into the code, I find that here is the guilty code :

```
// Check to see if all bits are set in LSR. If this is the case, it means
// the port I/O address is invalid as 0xFF is nonsense for LSR. This
// prevents writing a byte to non-existent hardware.

Lsr = Port->Read(Port, COM_LSR);
if (Lsr == SERIAL_LSR_NOT_PRESENT) {
return UartNotReady;
}
```

It seems that the port is not initialized as the **LSR** shows "**SERIAL_LSR_NOT_PRESENT=0xff**".

**Update 1:** I run all the above code in ring 0 (kernel mode).

So, my questions are :

1. According to what I read, Serial ports are I/O mapped and not Memory Mapped I/O (MMIO). Am I right?
2. The second question is, what's wrong with my code that makes LSR, 0xff, and I can't send data over this serial port? Did I miss anything?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about writing driver code for serial ports on a PC, not Electrical Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like serial port driver code, I am not surprised it does not run in user mode, and most importantly, that code only talks to 16550 type UARTs so that is unusable for USB serial ports for example. If you want to open and talk via COM ports, you open it like a file and use the serial port IOCTL routines on the file handle, as explained in Microsoft developer docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use a driver so I run the code in ring 0, not user-mode. I'm trying to use 16550, not a USB serial, the reason why I don't want to use user-mode is that I'm trying to write a kernel debugger (gdb-stub) for Windows.